# Infowindows doesn't show using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've read all of the posts about stackoverflow about "Infowindows doesn't show". It's not a problem of the map is created after the creation of the infowindow or any unexpected statement.

The maps shows with the marker on it, it can calculate routes, but when you click in the marker it doesn't show any info window. This is a tiny snippet of a whole program I've made, but I have made it reproducible in order to you to read it better. (API-Key not shown)

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&v=3.20&signed_in=false&libraries=places">    </script> 
    <title>Try</title>

    <script>


  function initialize() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -1),


     zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var carImage = 'car.png';
    var carLatLng = [];
    carLatLng[0] = new google.maps.LatLng(40, -1);

    var carMarker = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < carLatLng.length; j++) {
      var carMarkerPlotter = function(carMarker){
          carMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: carLatLng[j],
            map: map,
            icon: carImage,
            clickable: true
          });
      }(carMarker);
    }


    var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
        document.getElementById('pac-input'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

        var rendererOptions = [];
        var directionsDisplay = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < carLatLng.length; k++) {

            rendererOptions[k] = { map: map };
            directionsDisplay[k] = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions[k]);

            var request = {
                  origin: carLatLng[k],
                  destination: place.geometry.location,
                  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                };

            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var dir = function(directionsDisplay) {
              directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                } else alert('Failed to get directions');
              });
            }(directionsDisplay[k]);
          }

        }
      });

      var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: "Try"
     });

      google.maps.event.addListener(carMarker[0], 'click', function() {
        infowindow1.open(map,carMarker[0])
      });


    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help. It's been days since I'm having this problem.

EDIT:

- In Firefox's console it prints "TypeError: a is undefined". In main.js:17:1612
- In Chromium's console it prints "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined". In main.js:17
- JSFiddle not working (Haven't found the errors, It's the first time I use it): https://jsfiddle.net/oamjue5p/2/

Comment: While the code is useful, there's no information about how to reproduce the problem. What should go in the "Search" box? A more useful question would cite a working JSFiddle, I'm afraid.

Comment: Well then, let's add it...

Comment: It doesn't work in JSFiddle. I doesn't know why. The link is https://jsfiddle.net/oamjue5p/2/ but the question is simple and the explanations also simple: "Search" searches for a address and plots the directions on the map. All works except showing the InfoWindow

Comment: [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/oamjue5p/3/)

Comment: `carMarker` is a `google.maps.Marker` not an array, `Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.event.addListeners is not a function`

Comment: That was it. I forgot to write `carMarker[j]` instead of `carMarker` alone. I just could't see the error. How can I view it the next time so they doesn't give that much negative punctuation? Is there any debugger you have used? Please answer the question and I give you the reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210329/geocodezip) said,

> carMarker is a google.maps.Marker not an array,
>
> Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.event.addListeners is not a function